# Do Kubernetes services run on a particular node?

Tags: kubernetes

Where do ClusterIP and NodePort services run in Kubernetes? Do they run on a particular node, or do they run on all nodes? Is there a particular place where a service is running in Kubernetes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kubernetes services are not node specific. Services are just an abstraction of pods and a service can point to a pod regardless of where it runs in the cluster at any given moment in time.

For more info:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/